# Connecting Python to Oracle - input contains NaN infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') Error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

I am new in Oracle and Python and I connected my python to Oracle. I had this table on my Oracle database and I wanted to write a simple query to see my result but it gave me this error:

`Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

My code:

```
SQL_Query2 = pd.read_sql_query('''select Province_name, cnt from Provincepartnercnt''' , conn)
x_test = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query2, columns=['Province_name','cnt'])
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query('''select Province_name, cnt from Provincepartnercnt''' , conn)
x_train = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['Province_name','cnt'])
myKNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)
myKNN.fit(x_test, x_train)
```

Also my datatype are not `float`: one of my columns is in `VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)` and the other one is in `NUMBER(38,0)`. Also I have to mention that non of my rows are null or anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for) or [ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62702691)

Comment: Where does `KNeighborsClassifier` come from?

Comment: The most probable explanation is that you try to convert the `Province_name` to `float` which leads to `NaN`. Also *suspitious* is that you pass to `fit` two *identical* parameters (created by the same query). You should re-think what are your *features* and *target*

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to insert my data without using that query. Maybe the problem is using sklearn. ( I just simply use this code.)

My code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
query= cursor.execute("select ostan_name, cnt from ostanpartnercnt")

for row in re:
    print(row)
```